# Find the average of every list item in the same position of the List<List<Double>>

Tags: java, java-stream

Hi I want to find the average of a lisf of list of doubles and return list of doubles which is the average of original list how can I do this in java streams?

```
List<Double> comupteAverage(List<List<Double>> values)
{
    List<Double> averages=?;
    return averages;
}
```

Every returned list item is average of every list item in the same position in the original list.
I hope I could describe problem correctly.
Thanks.

Comment: You should show what did you do by yourself

Comment: did you try to use an interator/loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume all the lists have the same size. You can use `IntStream()` to traverse and sum the values on the same index of every list.

First iteration `IntStream.range(0, l1.size())` is to traverse the items from the first item of the lists to the end.

Second iteration `IntStream.range(0, values.size())` is to reach all items on the same index: `l1.get(0), l2.get(0),...`

To get the sum `l1.get(0) + l2.get(0) +...` :

`IntStream.range(0, values.size()).mapToDouble(j -> values.get(j).get(i)).sum()`

and divide by `values.size()` to get the average value.

Try this:

```
List<Double> l1 = Arrays.asList(2.0, 10.0, 7.0);
List<Double> l2 = Arrays.asList(7.0, 15.0, 7.0);
List<Double> l3 = Arrays.asList(3.0, 5.0, 7.0);
List<List<Double>> values = Arrays.asList(l1, l2, l3);

List<Double> avgList = IntStream.range(0, l1.size()).boxed()
        .map(i -> IntStream.range(0, values.size()).mapToDouble(j -> values.get(j).get(i)).sum()
                / Double.valueOf(values.size()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(avgList);
```

Output:

```
[4.0, 10.0, 7.0]
```

Comment: thanks Hülya I did it using for loops but I was looking for an more elegant way. just like what you did.